# svg rect and text element transition using CSS3 in jquery

Tags: css, svg, css-transitions, jquery-svg

Please refer below (tooltip)  SVG Group.

```
<g id="container_svg_TrackToolTip" transform="translate(83.5,446)">
<rect id="container_svg_ToolTipRect" x="318.75390625" y="-267.1015625" width="109.00390625" height="67" fill="white" stroke-width="1" stroke="black" fill-opacity="0.85" rx="0" ry="0"/><text id="container_svg_ToolTipText" x="326.7804718017578" y="-251.60000610351562" fill="#707070" font-size="12px" font-family="Segoe UI" font-style="Normal " font-weight="Regular" text-anchor="start" dominant-baseline="middle">
<tspan x="326.7804718017578" dy="0">pound</tspan>
<tspan x="326.7804718017578" dy="18">LiteracyRate0.248</tspan><tspan x="326.7804718017578" dy="18">Economic Rate35</tspan>
</text>
</g>
```

am going to modify the x and y position of rectangle whenever am oveing the specific point in chart.

i need some smooth transition of rect element as well as text element.

i referred the following links.

http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/05/how-to-make-smooth-transitions-with-css3/

http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2012/03/30/svg-animations-css-animations-css-transitions/

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/scalable-vector-graphic-css-styling/

i tried to set css of rect element via jquery like something

```
 $("#container_svg_ToolTipRect").css({
                'transition-property': 'x,y',
                '-moz-transition-property': 'x,y', /* Firefox 4 */
                '-webkit-transition-property': 'x,y', /* Safari and Chrome */
                '-o-transition-property': 'x,y',
                'transition-duration': "200ms",
                '-moz-transition-duration': "200ms", /* Firefox 4 */
                '-webkit-transition-duration':"200ms", /* Safari and Chrome */
                '-o-transition-duration': "200ms" /* Opera */
            });
```

but this will not do any changes. that means transition property is not working (no smooth transition)

i need to do same for text element too.

what's the problem. how can i do smooth transition for rect and text element by changing x and y attribute

something like

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<style>
    rect {
        fill: black;
    }

    rect:hover {
        fill: teal;
        transition-property: fill;
        transition-duration: 3s;
    }
</style>

<rect width="100" height="100" />
</svg>
```

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: x and y attributes are not styles and cannot be modified by css. You'll have to do it with javascript or SMIL animation.

Comment: @robert but we can modify the attributes of rectangle using css. please see my updated link

Comment: That's not what you're doing, you're applying an additional transform. You're not changing the x and y attributes because that's not possible with CSS.